# call block in second parent layout.twig.html symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, block

I want to execute a javascript in  when user enter in this page : page1.twig.html

```
    {% extends "Test1Bundle::layout1.html.twig" %}

   // block code javascript here

    {% block content %}
    <div>
        <span>Alexa .</span>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

---

layout1.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'Test1Bundle::layout2.html.twig' %}
<p>
My name is : {% block content %}{% content %}
</p>
```

---

layout2.html.twig :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
// call block javascript here
</head>
.
.
.
```

I don't know what I do for this and which function to use ! please help !

Comment: U need to define a block javascript in your base template. This u then can override, just like the same way with the content block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define empty blocks in your parents, where you want to see your stuffs rendered:

<kbd>page1.html.twig</kbd>:

```
{% extends "layout1.html.twig" %}

{% block script %}

 <script type="text/javascript">
   // whatever
 </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block name %}
<div>
    <span>Alexa .</span>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>layout1.html.twig</kbd>:

```
{% extends 'layout2.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<p>
My name is : {% block name %}{% endblock %}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>layout2.html.twig</kbd>:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
   {# btw, scripts are better at the bottom of the body #}
   {% block script %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

### See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/v4z4wr)